# JMeter output log to file in GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, log4j

As tittle, Is it possable to output log to file(.log or .txt) in GUI mode.

I tried every listener in Jmeter, but I can't drap log to file.

Log look like only show in log viewer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print something to *jmeter.log* file - use [__logn() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__logn)

[image]

If you don't want to include the [stacktrace](https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/java-stack-trace-understanding/) - you can go for [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function

[image]

JMeter by default stores its log file into [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it should create the file in its "bin" folder (or in the current working folder if it's different). You can also amend the log file location in the [*log4j2.xml* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), the line is

```
<File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. It's solve my problem.